# Dropdown list will not work for index 8 or 9 but works for all others that I test

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list on a webform.  It contains state names.  The dropdown list is populated using an xml file at page load.  When I select a specific state I have the onselectedindexchange event firing. When I select Florida which is index 9, the index changes to 7 which is conneticut.  I am lost as to what is going on.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am not a professional programmer.  Thanks

Here is the xml file data.

```xml
<state name="Delaware" abs="DE">
    <id>8</id>
    <counties>
        <county id="1">Kent</county>
        <county id="2">New Castle</county>
        <county id="3">Sussex</county>
    </counties>
</state>
<state name="Florida" abs="FL">
    <id>9</id>
    <counties>
        <county id="1">Alachua</county>
        <county id="2">Baker</county>
        <county id="3">Bay</county>
        <county id="4">Bradford</county>
        <county id="5">Brevard</county>
        <county id="6">Broward</county>
```

webpage control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" TabIndex="0"></asp:DropDownList>
```

codebehind

I am getting the index and then filling another listbox control with the counties for the state collected

```c#
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nodeid = ddlState.SelectedIndex;
    ddStateComm.SelectedIndex = nodeid - 1;
    countyfill(nodeid, sender);
    countyfill(ddStateComm.SelectedIndex + 1, ddStateComm);
    txtZipcode.Focus();
}
```

This is the code to get the county nodes for the state selected

```
protected void countyfill(int id, object sender)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(MapPath("\~/App_Data/counties.xml"));

    XmlNodeList ing = doc.SelectNodes("states/state[id = " + id + "]/counties/*");
    
    if (sender.Equals(ddStateComm))
    {
        lstCounties.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ing.Count; i++)
        {
            lstCounties.Items.Add(new ListItem(ing.Item(i).InnerText));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dpdCounty.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ing.Count; i++)
        {
              dpdCounty.Items.Add(new ListItem(ing.Item(i).InnerText));
        }
    
    }
}
```

I tried to move the states at indexes 8 and 9 to 51 and 52 to see if a change would happen.  All other states work fine.  I have checked the xml file just to make sure there in not some simple missing end tag causing the problem with those specific states but I don't see anything.

Comment: I tried to cleanup your XML (which is mostly unreadable in your original post).  It's not well-formed.  It only has data for two states (Delaware and Florida).  As it stands, it's unparsable.  What do you see when you debug your program

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes sorry about the XML.  I am aware that It was not the entire file. Thanks for fixing it. When I debug and select either Delaware or Florida the selected index reverts to 7 and will go through my county code using that index.  I have walked through the code but can't see where it is changing. I can send the XML file for review .

Comment: [link](https://www.acmenotary.com/acmenotaries.aspx)

Comment: Is your _link_ a link to the app, or are you spmming us?

Comment: yes, that is the page. you can see what is happening when you select Delaware and Florida. I have other issues but I am just working on this one for now.

Comment: What do you see when you debug this? Does `countyfill` behave the way you expect? When you look at the emitted HTML for thr page and the drop-down, is it what you expect?

Comment: When I walk through the code starting at the index changed event, the index is already 7 if I pick either Delaware or Florida at index 8 and 9 respectfully.  The 'countyfill' does work as expected as it is being fed the incorrect index of 7.  What bothers me is that if I pick a state at let's say index 40 everything works perfectly.  This is why I am confused.

Comment: So I created another project with a page with only the dropdown and a listbox.  The dropdown populates with the states on load.  After selecting the states in question I get the same results.  By the way I am using a different computer with the latest VS to test now.  I would think that the xml file has a problem or it is not formed correctly.  So I deleted those states from the xml file and the new states in those positions work fine Georgia and Hawaii.  I will try and add Delaware and FL in manually again and see what happens.

Comment: So I have figured it out.  In the XML file I have an attribute abr="CT" or state abbreviation.  On States starting at Connecticut through Florida I had written abs="CT".  After fixing that letter all is working as expected.  Thanks for sticking in there with me.  You didn't see the error because I didn't send enough of the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error was caused by an incorrectly formed XML file.  The attribute abr for abbreviation of state was misspelled on a few states as abs.  So in the code above you will notice the attribute abs="FL" which is fine if they were all that way.  All of the other states are using abr="State abbreviation" I hope this helps everyone. I should of had an XML Schema in place.